# UWP Webview has no resume function

Tags: webview, navigation, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

UWP Webview I am using it in C#/xaml app, to load websites, it has stop() method to halt the content  loading but when I want to resume content loading, after it being stopped, how can I do that? for example, I have several webviews on same page, and at start I halt all of them for good performance, but then according to user commands I want to resume their content loading, and then if I want to stop again I can stop, also does stop method means that it pauses the content load? or stops it completely? so that next time we have to navigate again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop is like the browser `"Stop"` button. It halts all content download and is not resumable.

You'll need to reload/refresh the page that you want to "resume." Depending on the web page, some of the content maybe cached locally already so to the user it may appear as if it loads more quickly.